# checking for prime number, why does my output not include 2?

Tags: python

```
def is_prime(num):
    for i in range (2, num):
        if num % i == 0:
            return False
        else:
            return True
        

for i in range(1, 20):
    if is_prime(i + 1):
        print(i + 1, end=" ")
print()
```

I think it has something to do with the range function and value of 2 in the lower code?

expected output - 2 3 5 7 9 11 13 15 17 19

my output - 3 5 7 9 11 13 15 17 19

Comment: if you return in both if and else, how many iterations of the for loop do you think you do?

Comment: Also, consider what the code `range (2, num)` does when `num` is 2.

Comment: You expect `9` and `15` in the output? The last time I checked, those numbers were not prime (3*3=9 and 3*5=15) but mathematics might have changed since. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `is_prime()`, when `num = 2`, the `for` loop is skipped entirely and the function returns `None`. `None` is a falsy value, so `2` is never printed.

Here is an `is_prime()` implementation that resolves this issue:

```py
def is_prime(num):
    for i in range(2, num):
        if num % i == 0:
            return False
    return num != 1
```

Comment: Is it skipped because the for in his initial statement because for i in range(2,2)? But in your case it exits the for loop and returns True instead.

Comment: Yes, though there should be a check for `1` which I've just edited in.

Comment: thank you for the help, so in the for loop when num is 2 and the range function is range(2,2) it returns none instead of an outright error? i didn't consider it at the time, but i thought the range stop HAS to be greater than the start?

Comment: It doesn't have to, no. If `stop >= start` (and `step` is non-negative) then the `range()` will simply have no elements in it.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try running the code `is_prime(2)`? After the first iteration (`i=2`), because the function has returned `False`, the function terminates. Just remember that if a `return` statement runs in a function, it stops, just as in a loop, the `break` command stops the loop. A better way to test if a number is prime would be to check every number until the SQUARE ROOT of the original:

```
def is_prime(n):
    if n == 1:
        return False
    i = 2
    while i*i <= n:
        if n % i == 0:
            return False
        i += 1
    return True

for x in xrange(1, 11):
    print '%d: %s' % (x, is_prime(x))
```